# Cannot save a new script on Pg Admin 4 while using Mac

Tags: macos, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to save an SQL script on my computer storage but the Create button is disabled.
Can anyone help with that. [In this image the create button is disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB3Ao.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can you fill in the address /Users/aish adding some filename ?
/Users/aish/db.sql